# dynamically filtering results from param by date 1.day.ago, 1.week.ago, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some filter params being sent to my controller:

```
params[:filter] = ["liked", "day"]
```

or

```
params[:filter] = ["top", "month"]
```

How I do something like this?

```
filter = params[:filter]
Post.all.where('created_at > ?', 1.filter[1].ago)
```

so that I can write one query that will handle 1.day.ago, 1.month.ago, etc.

instead of getting:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `filter' for 1:Fixnum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `send` to invoke a method by name:

```
Post.all.where('created_at > ?', 1.send(filter[1]).ago)
```